# How to compute 1000 prime numbers and store to an array

Tags: java, arrays

So I have to write a program that will compute the first 1000 prime numbers and store them into an array, print out the first 50 of those prime numbers, then prompt the user to enter an integer less than 1000 and check if its prime, if it is not prime then it will display the integer's smallest factors in increasing order.

I have the code sort of broken up now with certain pieces done, but can't quite figure out the first part that computes the 1000 prime numbers and stores it into an array. Then I not sure how to limit the printing of the prime numbers in that array to only the first 50 elements.

The code I have now is below, any help would be much appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //print out the first 50 primes
    System.out.println("The first 50 prime numbers are: \n");
    printPrimeNumbers(50);

    //integer that will be checked for being prime
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer:");
    int integer = input.nextInt();

    //if integer not prime then print out its smallest factors
    if(isPrime(integer) == false){
    int i = 2;
    String s = " ";

    //code for finding smallest factors
    while (integer != 1){
        if (integer % i == 0){
            s = s + ", " + i;
            integer = (integer / i);
            i = 2;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    System.out.print("The smallest factors are " + s.substring(2) + ".");
}

//checks whether integer is prime
public static boolean isPrime(int number){

    for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= (number/2); divisor++){
        if (number % divisor == 0){
            return false; 
        }
    }

    return true;
}

//needs to print first 50 of the 1000 prime numbers computed
public static void printPrimeNumbers(int numberOfPrimes){
    final int NUMBER_OF_PRIMES_PER_LINE = 10;
    int count = 0;
    int number =2;

    while(count < numberOfPrimes) {
        if(isPrime(number)){
            count++;
        }
        if(count % NUMBER_OF_PRIMES_PER_LINE == 0){
            System.out.printf("%-5s\n", number);
        }
        else
            System.out.printf("%-5s\n", number);
    }
    number++;
}
```

Comment: It's not all that different to your `printPrimeNumbers` - just storing them instead of printing. Why not calculate them all and store them and print from the stored data rather than calculating again?

Comment: So I could convert the printPrimeNumbers to say storePrimeNumbers by doing: public static int StorePrimeNumbers(int[] arrayPrimes) ? Would the effectively store the prime numbers i am calculating?

Comment: You can check if a number is prime by loop only 2 to sqrt(num). Check it out if you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a method `printPrimeNumbers` that generates the first x prime numbers. All you need to do is change that logic to store the numbers in an array instead of printing them. I did that and fixed a couple of errors in the method:

```
private static final int NUM_PRIMES = 1000;
private static final int FIRST_PRIME = 2;
private int[] primes;

public static void generatePrimes() {

    //initialize variables
    primes = new int[NUM_PRIMES];
    int count = 0;
    int number = FIRST_PRIME;

    //loop until the array is full
    while(count < NUM_PRIMES) {

        //if the number is prime
        if(isPrime(number)){

            //add it to the array and increment the array index / prime count
            primes[count] = number;
            count++;
        }

        //increment the number being checked
        number++;
    }
}
```

Then to print the elements is very simple:

```
for (int i = 0; i < primes.length; i++) {
 System.out.print(primes[i]);
}
```

Comment: ok ok so now the 1000 primes are stored in the array int [] primes, now how would i print only the first 50 elements n not the whole array?

Comment: @SZapata that is a really very basic question. Have you considered reading a basic java tutorial?

Comment: @SZapata See my edit. Basically you print them the same way you print them now. If this helped you an upvote and accepted answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @bhSpencer based on the question I would guess he is working his way through some "basic tutorials". Let's try to keep the community here supportive, as your comment could be discouraging to a new comer

Comment: Ways to do it with Java 8: https://thecannycoder.wordpress.com/